# How do you call in Libraries correctly?

Tags: c#, dll, reference, xna

I've looked around a lot.. and I haven't found anything to help me out.
This is the outcome I am looking for:

I am using XNA Game Studio 4.0, and I want to create my own library to use when making my game, so I don't have to rewrite code that I have previously used over and over every time I want to make a new game. So, I want to call in a library as a reference. My Library:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace iRaaptorLibraryXNA
{
    public class XNALibrary
    {
        public static void consolePrint(string text)
        {
            var timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString(@"hh:mm:ss tt");
            Console.WriteLine("[" + timeStamp + "] CONSOLE: " + text);
        }
    }
}
```

I use the consolePrint function a lot while debugging.
For example, if I wanted to print a line to show success, I'd like to be able to type

```
consolePrint("SUCCESS!")
```

and that prints it to console. I DONT want to have to repeatedly type in:

```
XNALibraryXNA.consolePrint("SUCCESS!");
```

I want to shorten it to just

```
consolePrint("SUCCESS!");
```

Here is my game code:

```
using iRaaptorLibraryXNA;

namespace xnaFun
{
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {

        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {

            base.Initialize() 
            XNALibrary.consolePrint("Initialized!");
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            iRaaptorLibraryXNA.consolePrint("Loading content!"); // DOES PRINT TO CONSOLE
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        }
```

etc......

I hope I included enough information.  ~iRaaptor

TL;DR I want to shorten

```
XMALibrary.consolePrint("text");
```

to

```
consolePrint("text");
```

Comment: What is the reason for not typing 1 word?

Comment: I'd rather type consolePrint than XMALibrary.consolePrint anyday. +I type consolePrint a lot in game debugging code block.. organization, and less typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this class to your library:

```
public class BaseGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    protected void consolePrint(string message)
    {
        XNALibrary.consolePrint("Initialized!");
    }
}
```

Your game class can then inherit from the basegame and use the `consolePrint` method:

```
public class MyGame : BaseGame
{       
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize() 
        consolePrint("Initialized!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me out by applying those changes to my code if possible please?

Comment: First add the `BaseGame` class to your library project. Then you change the base class of your Game1 class from `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game` to `BaseGame`. It should be as simple as that.